# How can I normalize fonts?

Tags: unicode, normalize

Users sometimes use weird ASCII characters in a program, and I was wondering if there was a way to "normalize" it.

So basically, if the input `ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢ`, the output would be `ABCDEFG`. Is there a dictionary that exists somewhere that does something like this? If not, is there a better method than just doing something like `str.replace("ᴀ", "A")` for all the different "fonts"?

This isn't a language specific question -- if something doesn't exist like this than I guess the next step is to create a dictionary myself.

Comment: Those are weird unicode characters, not ASCII characters at all....

Comment: @ChrisDodd Wow, I guess that's why I wasn't able to find a solution :( Thanks! I'll look into Unicode normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

BTW—The technical terms are: Latin Capital Letters from the C0 Controls and Basic Latin block and the Latin Letter Small Capitals from the Phonetic Extensions block.

Anyway, the general topic for your question is [Unicode confusables](https://www.unicode.org/Public/security/10.0.0/confusables.txt). The link is for a mapping. Uncode.org has more material on confusables and everything else Unicode.

(Normalization is always something to consider when processing Unicode text, but it doesn't particularly relate to this issue.)

Comment: This is very late, but this was exactly what I was looking for and ended up using! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your example seems to involve unicode characters, not ASCII characters.  [Unicode normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) ([FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html)) is a large and complex subject, with many difference equivalence classes of characters, depending on what you are trying to do.