# How to normalize fancy-looking unicode string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, unicode

I receive from a REST API a text with this kind of style, for example

- ?
- ?
- нσω тσ яємσνє тнιѕ ƒσηт ƒяσм α ѕтяιηg?

But this is not italic or bold or underlined since the type it's string.
This kind of text make it failed my Regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9._]*$`

I would like to normalize this string received in a standard one in order to make my Regex still valid.

Comment: There are a *lot* of possible characters to translate, and some of the replacements might be ambiguous.

Comment: These are Unicode characters (for instance, the first sentence have characters from [this range](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf)). Note that in the third there are greek and russian characters, that have no obvious latin equivalent (there are transliteration rules, but they are supposed to apply only to text written in a foreign language, not to this garbage).

Comment: What is your tech stack? Where are you able to make changes? For instance, could you just add a function to your own project to "collapse" text like this down to plain Roman letters, or would you need to put a reverse proxy in front of the REST API?

Comment: Agree with the other answers that these Unicode characters won't map cleanly back to English. **However**, if you know more information about the services used to create them, where you _know, with absolute 100% confidence_ these strings were originally plain-text English, and you'll _NEVER_ have real non-English text anywhere, you may be able to find out their maps and reliably run them backwards.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut It's not ciphered; it's stylized. It's mean to be readable, but "pretty". People do this all the time for things like facebook and twitter. So if you had, say, a social chat platform for you company where people do this, and now you've been asked to add a search feature, suddenly you need to handle this as "regular" text.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ah, yes, I see. If this comes from social network messages, this can happen.

Comment: [How can I normalize fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191921/how-can-i-normalize-fonts) contains the details for writing a solution, I believe. See the [Unicode confusables](https://www.unicode.org/Public/security/10.0.0/confusables.txt).

Comment: I just want to point out that what you call "English" character are actually characters from the "latin" alphabet. 
English is one of the languages that uses the latin alphabet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Unicode Compatibility normalization forms, which use Unicode's own (lossy) character mappings to transform letter-like characters (among other things) to their simplified equivalents.

In python, for instance:

```
>>> from unicodedata import normalize
>>> normalize('NFKD','       ')
'How to remove this font from a string'

# EDIT: This one wouldn't work
>>> normalize('NFKD','нσω тσ яємσνє тнιѕ ƒσηт ƒяσм α ѕтяιηg?')
'нσω тσ яємσνє тнιѕ ƒσηт ƒяσм α ѕтяιηg?'
```

[Interactive example here.](https://dencode.com/en/string/unicode-normalization)

Note that this only applies to stylistic forms (superscripts, blackletter, fill-width, etc.), so your third example, which uses non-latin characters, can't be decomposed to ASCII.

For C# [here's the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netcore-3.1) for String.Normalize, which does just that:

```
string s1 = "       ";
string s2 = s1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);
```

Comment: Example output on the last string ("нσω тσ яємσνє тнιѕ ƒσηт ƒяσм α ѕтяιηg") would be relevant to show limitations.

Comment: Yeah, I only realized that after replying. Edited my reply. There's probably no simple way to strip the style from the third string, it's akin to attempting to translate leet-speak at that point. You would need a translation table for all unicode characters that vaguely look like letters (but aren't actually stylized letters like with the first two strings).

Comment: A great resource for testing this kind of thing is the [big list of naughty strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings).