# Converting shaped font to normal font problem

Tags: c#, .net, string, special-characters

I have a string like :

`❤️`

I would like to get output like :

`KK❤️GG`

I tried a lot of ways such as I tried to change font with `ARIALUNI.TTF`. Also I tried to `Unidecode(UnidecodeSharpFork nuget package)`.

Note that : If it was a static situation, I could solve it with replace, but different letters may come.

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=net-6.0 do what you want?

Comment: eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959960/how-to-normalize-fancy-looking-unicode-string-in-c `.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to normalize fancy-looking unicode string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959960/how-to-normalize-fancy-looking-unicode-string-in-c)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ljlDqf